Book with a diamond statue, a creature in a diamond sleep coffin, a lazer mole, a diamond dome city and a war
This was a sci fi book I read in 5th grade about 1974.
There were 2 cities underground, at war. the boy found a diamond statue  n there were underwater caves.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was the spelling "lazer" actually used?  Do you remember the cover art?

It had a "creature from the black lagoon " lookin characters swimming.. yea it said Lazer in the body  of the book ..seams like it had the creatures  name in the title..

Was the "creature" in the coffin revealed to be a man but referred to as a "hero?" Also do the terms "daggertooth," "vatkid," or "Oddlies" sound familiar? If so, I know a 1973 novel that fits a lot of this.

@Cassfrank I guess you mean The Hero of Downways, but there's no diamond statue in that book nor any lasers.
